# What is the problem in this command line (sqlite)

Tags: sqlite

```sql
 CREATE TABLE
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 origin TEXT NOT NULL,      
 destination TEXT NOTNULL,
 duration INTEGER NOTNULL
  ;
```

> Error: near "INTEGER": syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the table's name and spaces between NOT and NULL. This should work:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 origin TEXT NOT NULL,      
 destination TEXT NOT NULL,
 duration INTEGER NOT NULL)
  ;
```